# Rider IDE - Razor Pages HTML Highlighting?

Tags: rider

Does Rider really not provide HTML-Highlighting in Razor Pages like in the image bellow? Or where I need to configure it? Couldn't find an answer.

[image: Highlighting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a razor specific problem, but a bug in color schemes. Switch to ReShaper Dark/Visual Studio Dark in 'Settings | Editor | Color Schemes'. This is also fixed in 2019.1 ([2019.1 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/eap/) is available)

Comment: Thank you =) Oh 2019.1 is avaible, awesome! Great job btw!